# C macro to paste tokens

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a macro defined as below

```
#define X_T_a(b)            b->a
```

b = pointer to a struct,
a = field in that struct

I want to define another macro T(a,b) that resolves to X_T_a(b)

Should I use

```
#define T(a, b)             X_T_##a(b)
```

or

```
#define T(a,b)   X_T(a,b)
#define X_T(a,b)   X_T_##a(b)
```

both works for the input I use.. But I am not much familiar with using macros.
I want to understand if some input can break these..

Answer (score 1):

Single macro version doesn't work with macro symbols.

For example, say you have:

```
#define MACRO_OBJECT   realObject
#define MACRO_MEMBER   realMember
T(MACRO_OBJECT, MACRO_MEMBER)
```

You want this to expand to `X_T_realObject(realMember)`.

If you use your first version, you will get `X_T_MACRO_OBJECT(realMember)`, because concatenation operator `##` will work before `MACRO_OBJECT` is expanded to `realObject`.

Comment: Should it be 
#define X_T(a,b)   X_T_##a(b)
or
#define X_T(a,b)  X_T_##a##(b)

How does it know to paste a and (  ?

Comment: @Parzival I *think* that `##` between `a` and `(` is not necessary, as they are separate preprocessor token types (identifier and punctuator).